# Tizen native UI creation

Tags: tizen

I'm trying to create a native Tizen app for my smartwatch.

However I'm struggling with UI creation, because creating everything by hand is very awfully slow and complex, and UI Builder has way too much limitation (genlist can not be added to naviframe directly, you have to have a box in between them which ruins the circular scroll totally).

There is somewhat called EDC, but please let me know: how are professionals creating applications for these smartwatches?

Hybrid? Web UI and C++ backend? My intention is to create a fast and lightweight application.

Comment: Hello, I recommend to use .NET dev environment to create Wearabe apps / Watchface. Your dev environment : Visual Studio + Visual Studio Tizen Plugin + Enhanced Project (You can create project with several basic features) + Xamarin.Forms as UI framework + Tizen.CircularUI for wearable specific...

Comment: https://docs.tizen.org/application/dotnet/get-started/wearable/first-app/

Comment: Visual Studio - extension search : Keyword - Tizen. You can find "Visual Studio Tools for Tizen" and "Tizen Template Studio (beta)"

Comment: Introduction for Tizen Template Studio: https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/blog/en-us/2020/06/12/announcing-tizen-template-studio